# Merge Pandas Dataframe and group by bitwise_or of many values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, group-by

I have two Pandas DataFrames:

The first one contains a pattern value for persons between dates:

```
access_pattern = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "person":    ['John',   'John',   'Peter',  'Charly'],
        "from_date": [20180101, 20180101, 20180201, 20180201],
        "to_date":   [20180108, 20180331, 20180228, 20180228],
        "pattern":   [10, 1, 11, 0]
    }
)

access_pattern["from_date"] = pd.to_datetime(access_pattern["from_date"], unit='m')
access_pattern["to_date"] = pd.to_datetime(access_pattern["to_date"], unit='m')
```

The second one contains the actual accesses of each person:

```
access = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "person": ['John', 'John', 'Peter', 'Charly'],
        "access_date": [20180107, 20180327, 20180226, 20180223]
    }
)

access["access_date"] = pd.to_datetime(access["access_date"], unit='m')
```

I want to merge this two Dataframes in order to obtain:

For each access in the access dataframe, I want the result of a bitwise_or of all the patterns that match the person and date in the access_pattern. In the case of the access date, it matches if it is between the from_date and to_date of the access pattern Dataframe.

Expected output:

```
John   20180107 11 # bitwise_or(10, 1)
John   20180327  1
Peter  20180226 11
Charly 20180223  0
```

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: Added in the body of the Question.

Comment: second row of `access`, does not have its date in the range, why we do the bitwise or for both the records?

Comment: @harvpan sorry it was my fault. I've corrected the "to_date" in the access_pattern dataframe.